# Delphi - Colordialog select Black as color

Tags: delphi, background-color, colordialog

I'm new in Delphi and I need some help.

I have program, a background color changer, with a `TColorDialog`. This works otherwise perfectly, but there is a problem with it when I close the `ColorDialog` without choosing a color from it. Then the background is changing in to black and it also save black as color "0" in the `.ini` file.

my code:

````
procedure TEinstellungenF.BtnBackgroundClick(Sender: TObject);
var filename:String;
ini:TIniFile;
begin       // Speichert die im ColorDialog ausgewählten Background Farben in der Ini
  filename := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Einstellungen.ini';
  ini := TIniFile.Create(filename);
  ColorDialog1.Execute();
  try
    ini.WriteInteger('Farben','Hintergrundfarbe', ColorDialog1.Color);
  finally
    ini.Free;
  end;

  FrmMain.Color := TColor(Ini.ReadInteger('Farben','Hintergrundfarbe',ColorDialog1.Color));
  Color := TColor(Ini.ReadInteger('Farben','Hintergrundfarbe',ColorDialog1.Color));
end;```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the returned value of `ColorDialog1.Execute` and act accordingly.

From the docs:

> Execute opens the color-selection dialog, returning true when the user selects a color and clicks OK, or false when the user cancels.

Comment: Thank you! That really helps me out. Appreciate your help

Comment: You are welcome! Please consider accepting the answer (click the tick mark, beside the answer, green). After you have earned some "reputation" you can also upvote / downvote answers. It is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)